# Whats the most efficient way of rendering 3D objects in DirectX9 [C++]?

Tags: c++, directx

sorry if I'm not specific enough, I'm new to DirectX programming and to Stack Overflow.

The problem is that when I'm rendering 3D objects in DirectX9, I have to manually add the Vertex Buffers and the Index Buffers (draw the cubes by hand). I'm trying to recreate a 'Minecraft' like world but don't know how I would go about it.

I've tried using 'for loops' but that just glitched the entire screen out. I've also attempted using vectors but I just got way to confused and didn't get anywhere.

This is the code I have. As you can see, this is the way I'd draw 2 cubes. I'm wondering if there is another more efficient way since I'd be wanting to draw hundreds of cubes at a time.

```
void DirectXClass::init_graphics(void)
{
    // create the vertices using the CUSTOMVERTEX struct
    CUSTOMVERTEX vertices[] =
    {
        // Square 1
        { 3.0f, 3.0f, -3.0f, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 0, 255), },
        { -3.0f, 3.0f, -3.0f, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 255, 0), },
        { 3.0f, -3.0f, -3.0f, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255, 0, 0), },
        { -3.0f, -3.0f, -3.0f, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 255, 255), },
        { 3.0f, 3.0f, 3.0f, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 0, 255), },
        { -3.0f, 3.0f, 3.0f, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255, 0, 0), },
        { 3.0f, -3.0f, 3.0f, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 255, 0), },
        { -3.0f, -3.0f, 3.0f, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 255, 255), },

        { -3.0f, 3.0f, 3.0f, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 0, 255), },
        { 3.0f, 3.0f, 3.0f, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 255, 0), },
        { -3.0f, -3.0f, 3.0f, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255, 0, 0), },
        { 3.0f, -3.0f, 3.0f, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 255, 255), },
        { -3.0f, 3.0f, 9.0f, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 0, 255), },
        { 3.0f, 3.0f, 9.0f, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255, 0, 0), },
        { -3.0f, -3.0f, 9.0f, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 255, 0), },
        { 3.0f, -3.0f, 9.0f, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 255, 255), },

        };

    // create a vertex buffer interface called v_buffer
    //  d3ddev->CreateVertexBuffer(sizeof(vertices) / sizeof(vertices[0]) * sizeof(CUSTOMVERTEX),
    d3ddev->CreateVertexBuffer(sizeof(vertices) / sizeof(vertices[0]) * sizeof(CUSTOMVERTEX),
        0,
        CUSTOMFVF,
        D3DPOOL_MANAGED,
        &v_buffer,
        NULL);

    VOID** pVoid;

    // lock v_buffer and load the vertices into it
    v_buffer->Lock(0, 0, (void**)& pVoid, 0);
    memcpy(pVoid, vertices, sizeof(vertices));
    v_buffer->Unlock();

    short indices[] =
    {
        0, 1, 2,    // side 1
        2, 1, 3,
        4, 0, 6,    // side 2
        6, 0, 2,
        7, 5, 6,    // side 3
        6, 5, 4,
        3, 1, 7,    // side 4
        7, 1, 5,
        4, 5, 0,    // side 5
        0, 5, 1,
        3, 7, 2,    // side 6
        2, 7, 6,

            8, 9, 10,    // side 9
            10, 9, 11,
            12, 8, 14,    // side 10
            14, 8, 10,
            15, 13, 14,    // side 11
            14, 13, 12,
            11, 9, 15,    // side 12
            15, 9, 13,
            12, 13, 8,    // side 13
            8, 13, 9,
            11, 15, 10,    // side 14
            10, 15, 14,
    };

    // create a vertex buffer interface called v_buffer
    //  d3ddev->CreateIndexBuffer(sizeof(indices) / sizeof(indices[0]) * sizeof(short),
    d3ddev->CreateIndexBuffer(sizeof(indices) / sizeof(indices[0]) * sizeof(short),
        0,
        D3DFMT_INDEX16,
        D3DPOOL_MANAGED,
        &i_buffer,
        NULL);

    // lock v_buffer and load the vertices into it
    i_buffer->Lock(0, 0, (void**)& pVoid, 0);
    memcpy(pVoid, indices, sizeof(indices));
    i_buffer->Unlock();
}
```

Comment: If you want draw more cubes at a time then you can use instancing. It's much more efficient

Comment: You've chosen a difficult task to start as to render a big Minecraft world needs a lot effort to run smoothly. But don't refrain from trying just for the first results I would recommend to just start draw cubes one by one as instancing is a topic to learn after learning the basics. As a first start you could draw your vertexbuffer multiple times in a for loop and then use a world matrix to move the cubes to the right position (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/direct3d9/world-transform, if you are using own shaders you will have to pass the matrix to it and then transform there)

Comment: Nvm, I've got the translation working now, however, it doesn't reproduce the cube, it only moves it. https://pastebin.com/S9AqxQN2